# SPAdminv4 Must be stopped to Run Various tasks

Tags: administration, stsadm

This is a very bizarre issue. Let me tell you our environment. SharePoint 2013 Enterprise, three server farm. Database, App, and WFE. A migration from 2010 happened about 6 months ago.

In order to Start/Stop Services Provision/Unprovision services or Deploy/Retract solutions. We have to follow these steps.

1. Use Central Admin to either start/stop/deploy/retract.
2. Stop the SPAdminv4 service
3. Run stsadm -o execadmsvcjobs
4. Start the SPAdminv4 service

If we don't do this, Central admin and Powershell will be stuck on starting/stopping/deploying/retracting. We have confirmed that other TimerJobs will complete. We have tested starting/stopping etc with using powershell, and we had the same issue.

What could be causing this? It's weird that we must run some deprecated powershell command to complete a simple task.

EDIT:
ran `Get-SPProduct -Local`
The Output for both servers was

```
ProductName                    Required   Missing              Servers             
-----------                    --------   -------              -------             
Microsoft SharePoint Server... True                            {}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had this problem before. You probably need to run the PowerShell command

```
Get-SPProduct -Local
```

Also I would try to run the PSConfig on all servers.

More here: http://thesharepointfarm.com/2013/12/the-magic-of-get-spproduct-local/

Comment: Even after reading that a few times, I'm not sure what a Get Command is doing that could remedy this problem, I have edited my answer to include the output. Thank you for showing me Get-SPProduct

Comment: Can you run a psconfig? Running this command allows your SharePoint to detect required software that would otherwise be blocking the sync in the farm.

Comment: You are very close to an accepted answer. We ran the powershell command and psconfig wizard on both servers. I decided to start/stop with central admin on the WFE the Excel Calculation Services. And it worked! However on the APP server I was able to STOP excel Calculation services, but now it's stuck on starting.

Comment: Do you have a healthy Excel Services Service Application? I'd check the settings on that. Also have you tried restarting?

Comment: It looks like it just took an extremely long time. Which I didn't think I've ever seen it take nearly 30 minutes to unprovision. I love you.

Comment: It's not working again, we have to run the command for solutions still.

Comment: Are all servers and db server on the same timezone?

Comment: Same Time zone and same daylight savings!

Comment: Check the timer jobs and delete the one-time jobs, and restart the sptimer service, before you try to deploy again. You may need to reset the sp config cache, read here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jamesway/archive/2011/05/23/sharepoint-2010-clearing-the-configuration-cache.aspx

Comment: Should APP and Web both be running SPTimer? Our Central Admin is on the WFE. Should SPAdminv4 only be running on the WFE then? Let me Delete ALL one time jobs, some of them looked important

Comment: SPTimerv4 is a crucial service that syncs the server with the rest of the farm's servers. It should always be running on every SharePoint server. If One-Time jobs are in the definitions, they aren't running correctly. One-time timer jobs are created by SharePoint and the definitions are deleted after they run successfully.

Comment: So what about spadminv4?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34981/discussion-between-mike-and-christopher-clark).

Comment: Okay, so I stopped sptimerv4 and spadminv4 on all servers. I deleted every timerjob that was .Schedule.Description = One-Time with powershell. I am starting up the services now
Stopped the services, and did a cleared the cache. Restarted services
Local Server Event ID error 6398 The Execute method of job definition Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPUpgradeJobDefinition (ID db0d105d-30d2-4af7-801c-9ed8e3f250d8) threw an exception. More information is included below. 

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
This "Upgrade Job" is showing failed in the timer job.